# $http post запросы отправляют данные в url

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, post

При отправке $http post данные передаются в url в виде строки

Сам код запроса

```
$http({
    url:"/back/backend/web/index.php?r=register/view",
    method: "POST",
    params:{
      id : user_id,
      auth : auth_key
    }
})
.then(
  function(response){
    return response.data;
  }
)
```

В консоле вижу такую картину 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается что params ничего не передает с помощью POST, все параметры на сервер отдаються GET-ом.

Версия  AngularJS v1.3.15

Как правильно описать параметры запроса ?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как говорит документация,

> params – {Object.} – Map of strings or objects which will be serialized with the paramSerializer and appended as GET parameters.

А вам нужно `data`:

> data – {string|Object} – Data to be sent as the request message data.

Comment: Благодарю, понял свой косяк :)

Answer (score 0):

добавьте данные в data:

```
$http({
    url:"/back/backend/web/index.php?r=register/view",
    method: "POST",
    data:{
      id : user_id,
      auth : auth_key
    }
})
.then(
  function(response){
    return response.data;
  }
)
```